# enabling scrolling hstore key/value field

Tags: qgis, postgresql

The `key/value` widget applied on a Postgres hstore field conveniently shows, for a record, a sub-table containing the various keys and values. If there isn't enough space in the form, this sub-table is resized and some key/values are not visible.

How can one scroll this sub-table? I am currently using QGIS 3.4.15 LTR.

Hstore field using the key/value widget:
[image]

Sub-table shows an elevator but is not scrollable:
[image]

Long enough form allows showing more fields in the sub-table
[image]

**edit**

Let's note that the scrolling works if the layer is being edited and is editable (i.e. it does not work with a read-only user)

[image]

Comment: Even in edit mode ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo It works if the layer is edited + editable, but it does not if the user is a read-only user (please see edit)

Comment: it's logic for me because in read only, the widget is not enabled and the scrolling is not possible. A workaround may be to place the `tags` fields in another tab ?

Comment: what do you mean by "another tab"?

Comment: Don't auto-generate your form, choose the drag & drop Designer mode and organize your fields (click on the green + for add a tab). [See the doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-drag-and-drop-designer)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It allows displaying 4.5 rows, then if I make the form longer it is filled by empty (grey) space, so it seems to improve the situation but not to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround may be to create, in a Drag & Drop Designer a new tab with the Key/Value widget, to access in edit mode if needed.

For read-only mode, add in the main tab, a HtmlWidget with the following code :

```js
<script>
document.write(expression.evaluate(
"'<ul>' || " +
  "with_variable(" +
  "'hstore'," +
  "hstore_to_map(\"tags\")," +
  "array_to_string(" +
    "array_foreach(" +
      "map_akeys(@hstore)," +
      "'<li>' || @element || ': ' || map_get(@hstore, @element) || '</li>'" +
    "), '', ''" +
  ")" +
")" +
"|| '</ul>'"
));
</script>
```

This will display a Html frame with the `tags` values as a list like :

> - alt_name: Mount King
> - wikidata: Q59320
> - wikipedia: en:King Peak (Yukon)

---

**EDIT**

If you want a pretty table styled with mouse hovering, you can add CSS style :

```html
<style>
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
document.write(expression.evaluate(
"'<table>' || " +
"'<tr><th>Tags</th>' || " +
  "with_variable(" +
  "'hstore'," +
  "hstore_to_map(\"tags\")," +
  "array_to_string(" +
    "array_foreach(" +
      "map_akeys(@hstore)," +
      "'<tr><td>' || @element || ': ' || map_get(@hstore, @element) || '</tr></td>'" +
    "), '', ''" +
  ")" +
")" +
"|| '</table>'"
));
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome!! For the benefit of others, let's note that `HtmlWidget` is not in 3.4 but in 3.10. Also I had to replace `"hstore_to_map('\"tags"')," +` with `"\"tags\"," +` as the field is already recognized as a map (and re-mapping it produces a Null output)

Comment: The output size adapts very well to the form, and is scrollable if there isn't enough space, perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: +1 pretty good catch!

Comment: @JGH: (QGIS 3.8). I've added a table style example and I let `hstore_to_map` for fully answering the question title (*who can do more, can do less*).

Comment: Thanks again! This new feature is really great! ... it will be a serious "competitor" to the virtual fields